# Ruby: Conditional replace in String using gsub

Tags: ruby, regex, replace, conditional-statements

Given an input string:

```
<m>1</m>
<m>2</m>
<m>10</m>
<m>11</m>
```

I would like to replace all values that are not equal to `1` with `5`.
So the output String should look like:

```
<m>1</m>
<m>5</m>
<m>5</m>
<m>5</m>
```

I tried using:

```
gsub(/(<m>)([^1])(<\/m>)/, '\15\3')
```

But this will not replace `10` and `11`.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm kind of curious why.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`#gsub` can optionally take a block and will replace with the result of that block:

```
subject.gsub(/\d+/) { |m| m == '1' ? m : '5' }
```

Comment: what I needed in the end was something like this:
gsub(/(<m>)(\d+)(<\/m>)/) {
  | m1 | m1.gsub(/\d+/) {
    | m2 | if ['1', '2', '4'].include?(m2)
      m2
    else
      '5'
    end
    }
  }

Comment: If you're using Ruby 1.9 you can use the pattern /(?<=<m>)(\d+)(?=<\/m>)/ to simplify it. The (?<=...) and (?=...) are a lookbehind and a lookahead, and those won't be included in the matched string.

Comment: or you can use $1, $2 and $3 in the block and just ignore the parameter: `subject.gsub(/(<m>)(\d+)(<\/m>)/) { |m| $1 + ($2 == '1' ? $2 : '5') + $3 }`

Answer (score 4):

Without regexp just because it's possible

```
"1 2 10 11".split.map{|n| n=='1' ? n : '5'}.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
result = subject.gsub(/\b(?!1\b)\d+/, '5')
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b    # match at a word boundary (in this case, at the start of a number)
(?!   # assert that it's not possible to match
 1    # 1
 \b   # if followed by a word boundary (= end of the number)
)     # end of lookahead assertion
\d+   # match any (integer) number
```

Edit:

If you just wish to replace numbers that are surrounded by `<m>` and `</m>` then you can use

```
result = subject.gsub(/<m>(?!1\b)\d+<\/m>/, '<m>5</m>')
```